# How do I update a row in MySQL using php?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I update the row $pageviews by +1 each time someone visits my page. The table name is news and the row to be updated is $pageviews whose default value is +1. Should I use the update function? And how do I implement it? Below is my code. Can you show a demonstration using these data?

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{  
    $id = $info['id'];
    $pageviews = $info['pageviews'];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `UPDATE news SET pageviews = pageviews + 1` ??

Comment: Oligatory "mysql is deprecated, use mysqli_* functions" comment. php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Yes I have tried it. Maybe I couldn't properly implement it. A demonstration would be really helpful.

Comment: Just pass the query I gave it on your `mysql_query()` function.. Note : You are using an obsolete database API.

Comment: I'm now changing my functions to mysqli_* function. Thank you.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran - That should really be an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this query

```
mysql_query("Update news SET pageviews = pageviews + 1 ");
```

or

store the current page id in $current_page_id.

```
 mysql_query("Update news SET pageviews = pageviews + 1  where id = '$current_page_id' ");
```

Comment: Could you please clarify how I can store the current page id in $current_page_id ?

Comment: your news table will have unique id, which you will send in url. After that, url will be like http://example.com/news.php?id=33. So in this case, id is 33. So in the new.php, you must write the code like. $current_page_id = $_GET['id']; then you have to use the above 2nd query

Answer (score 1):

All you want to do is to increment `pageviews` value each time that page renders. All you need for that:

1) Get the current value

2) Run `UPDATE` query updating current value + 1

To do so, you can write a function that would look like as,

```
function inc_page_views($id) {

  $res = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE `id` ='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($id))); 

  $data = mysql_fetch_array($res);

  // Target view count
  $target = $data['pageviews'];

  $query = sprintf("UPDATE `news` SET `pageviews` = '%s' WHERE `id` ='%s'", $target + 1, $id);

  return mysql_unbuffered_query($query);
}
```

And then, when rendering a page, you can simply call `inc_page_views(..here page id..)` and it will do the rest